# What is MySQL Cluster's Practical Memory Limit?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

We are designing a cloud SaaS, and are actively considering **MySQL Cluster** choice for our DB. We will be writing more than 100M rows/day to the DB. We need to understand if there is any practical memory limit.

I understand that MySQL Cluster supports at max 48 data nodes, but is there practically any limit on the RAM each data node can have? RAM will be anyways expensive but we want to eliminate this if there is any hard limit.

The question stems from this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-ndb-innodb-engines.html, where Storage Limit is mentioned as **3TB**. It is slightly ambiguous to understand the way it is written.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I read it, there is a 64GB limit per node.  48 nodes, without redundancy, would allow 3TB total data size, 1.5TB with redundancy.

That sounds like less than a day's worth of data at the rate you are ingesting data.

Do you need all the raw data?  Or can you summarize the data, then throw away (or archive to text files) the raw data?  This would probably let you collect data for 10 times as long.